# Gnome-shell takes all of cpu after last update of Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome-shell

Gnome-shell takes all of cpu after last update of Ubuntu 18.04. 
Even I can't open terminal to check anything.
Any idea?

Comment: It's 99% comes from graphic driver that is x.org.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved.**
Just need to update NVIDIA graphic driver to 396 and change display driver in Software & Updates.